# Does infrared radiation emitted by an object happen only from its surface, or is emission also from the centre of the object?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, material-science, infrared-radiation

Textbook answer of how radiation is emitted is from the surface.  Does the inside of a object also emit infrared?

Answer (score 2):

If you are analyzing an object that is opaque to infrared radiation (as most are), then any infrared radiation that is created inside would quickly run into a different part of the object and be absorbed.

For the purpose of thermal equilibrium, only surface radiation needs to be considered, because that is the only radiation that allows energy to leave the object.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by some kind of statement distinguishing what kinds of objects are opaque to infrared and over what kinds of distances. I don't think "as most are" is really justifiable as a blanket statement.

Answer (score 0):

Blackbody radiation is emitted from **both the surface and the insides of a body**. An ideal blackbody has its surface temperature in thermal equilibrium with its insides, so one can think of it as radiation being effectively emitted from its surface. However, for a real blackbody, the entire body emits radiation.

Answer (score 0):

If an infrared photon is somehow generated *inside a piece of metal* it immediately smacks into a metal atom in the metallic lattice and its electromagnetic energy is converted into vibrational energy which then diffuses away into the lattice as *heat*. Not until the heat vibrations reach the *surface* of the metal does it become possible for an infrared photon to be emitted *into space* (which is transparent to IR photons) from the surface.